# Plesk, Centos And Curl -: curl: command not found

Tags: curl, centos, cron

I need to configure some cron job.  But I get in my mailbox this error

> -: curl: command not found.

And the task is not running.

I tried to install Cron on the server

```
yum install curl
yum install php-common
yum install php-curl
yum install curl
```

and I have restart apache...

But it don't work, alaways the same error..

I am on CentOS.

Any idea?

Comment: You have to install `curl`, not `php-curl`.

Comment: Sorry I have forget to write.. I have install,  yum install curl

Comment: OK just updated your question with that info.

Comment: cron jobs often don't have the environment you expect them to have, try a full path to the binary in the cron script?

Comment: It's ok, Plesk bug.  I have to give right to the plesk user. Now it work. thank's for your help ;)

Answer (score 0):

Please specify the php version as well. Example if your server consists php 5.6 than run  `yam install php5.6-curl`